# Is it possible to create a vector of bitsets?

Tags: c++, vector, bitset

I am trying to create a vector of bitsets in C++. For this, I have tried the attempt as shown in  the code snippet below:

```
vector<bitset<8>> bvc;
    while (true) {
        bitset<8> bstemp( (long) xtemp );
        if (bstemp.count == y1) {
            bvc.push_back(bstemp);
        }
        if ( xtemp == 0) {
            break;
        }
        xtemp = (xtemp-1) & ntemp;
    }
```

When I try to compile the program, I get the error that reads that `bvc` was not declared in the scope. It further tells that the template argument 1 and 2 are invalid. (the 1st line). Also, in the line containing `bvc.push_back(bstemp)`, I am getting an error that reads invalid use of member function.

Comment: If it helps, I am willing to post the entire code. Although, I got down voted in a previous question for posting irreverent portion of code. Hence I put only the shorter version here.

Comment: By the way, it would help a lot if you post the actual errors you're getting from the compiler, instead of describing how you understand them.

Comment: Here is the error I get after I change vector<bitset<8>> to vector <bitset<8> > (as suggested in the answers.
`In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
 error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)`

Comment: Doesn't help much without letting us know whats on line 110, does it:)

Comment: @littleadv Sorry with the line number once again. On 110 its
`bvc.push_back(bstemp);`

Comment: `bstemp.count` should be `bstemp.count()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have a feeling that you're using pre C++11.

Change this:

```
vector<bitset<8>> bvc;
```

to this:

```
vector<bitset<8> > bvc;
```

Otherwise, the `>>` is parsed as the right-shift operator. This was "fixed" in C++11.

Comment: the term is called **Maximal munch** if someone is interested for further readings.

Answer (score 7):

Change `vector<bitset<8>> bvc` to `vector<bitset<8> > bvc`. Note the space. `>>` is an operator.

Yes, pretty nasty syntax issue.